# Differential signals passing within 6 mils of ground vias?

Tags: differential

It's puzzling I couldn't find the answer to this in the top 3 pages of google results.

I've got 4 DIMM240's routing to a single LX150 fpga.

Crowded in other words.

I'm supposed to keep 20 mils from anything else.

But can I pass within 6 mils of a ground via?

How about a +1.8V via, the voltage of the signal?

Speed is only 1600Mz for the data signal changes.

But if it would be bad for faster, I'd like to understand that.

Each differential has it's own ground plane adjacent to it.  3.5 mils away, or 8 mils away if it's embedded.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did the "20 mils from anything else" requirement come from?  That may be the recommended separation from a parallel trace.  And what is the spacing between the S+ and S- in a diff pair?

Comment: From a summary of 10 datasheets. But in particular, Micron's recommended layout for DDR2.  They actually wanted 25 at one point.   Differential pairs are recommended by Micron to be  8 mili with 5 mil spaces, but that didn't take into account my core thickness (3.5mils), so I redid that to 7 traces with 5 mil seperation.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally frowned upon to break rules like that.  By "frowned upon" I mean you really need to have hyperlynx or a similar simulator to see what the effects are.  If this is part of a bus then I would be worried about the imbalance of this pair being earlier or later than the others on the bus.  If you are running some async diff pair at that speed then you will likely be in better shape.

Comment: Ok, frowned upon I can live with, if I must.  Also, it's an FPGA.  Not a memory controller. I can shift any clock or bit any direction I want to.  So some of the r ules are kind of pointless when you aren't grabbing all bits at the same instant only.  I grabe in bytes, then stitch them back to my 256 bit wide memory.  But if I have to shift any clock more than 30%, stitching will become very difficult.